# Can the fidelity $F(\rho,\sigma)$ be computed knowing only $\rho - \sigma$?

Tags: fidelity, trace-distance

The motivation for this question comes from trace distance. For any two states $\rho, \sigma$, the trace distance $T(\rho, \sigma)$ is given by

$$T(\rho, \sigma) = |\rho - \sigma|_1,$$

where $|\cdot|_1$ is the 1-norm and given by $|X|_1 = \text{Tr}(\sqrt{X^\dagger X})$. The point here is that I do not need to know $\rho$ or $\sigma$ to compute the trace distance between them. All I need to know is $\rho - \sigma$.

Can one also compute $F(\rho,\sigma)$ where $F$ is the fidelity if one is only given $\rho - \sigma$? I am aware of bounds that can be placed using the trace distance on $F(\rho,\sigma)$ but was wondering if it could be exactly computed.

Comment: How many examples did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no, as the following counter-example reveals. Let $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ and define
$$
\rho_0  = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1+\varepsilon}{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1-\varepsilon}{2}
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\rho_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1-\varepsilon}{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1+\varepsilon}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
as well as
$$
\sigma_0  = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\varepsilon & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1-\varepsilon & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\sigma_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1-\varepsilon & 0\\
0 & 0 & \varepsilon
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The differences agree,
$$
\rho_0 - \rho_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
\varepsilon & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -\varepsilon
\end{pmatrix} = \sigma_0 - \sigma_1,
$$
but the fidelities are not equal:
$$
\mathrm{F}(\rho_0,\rho_1) = \sqrt{(1 + \varepsilon)(1-\varepsilon)}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mathrm{F}(\sigma_0,\sigma_1) = 1-\varepsilon.
$$